# jqGrid : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAccessor' of undefined while reading xml data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

My jqGrid works fine, loads data properly. Even sorting and pagination are working fine.
But, when filterToolBar is used to search data, it doesn't search any data...just keeps showing 'Loading...'.

Below are script taggings included in **HEAD** part:

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
 <script src="~/Scripts/js/src/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="jqGrid" ></table>
<div id="pager"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url: "GetData.asmx/LoadData",
    datatype: "xml",     
    xmlReader: {
        repeatitems: false,            
        root: "Rowset",
        row: "Row"
    },
    colNames: ["Id","Contact Name", "City", "Country"],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 40, stype: 'text',sortable:true },
        { name: "ContactName", index: "ContactName", sortable: true, width: 300,        search: true, stype: 'text' },
        { name: "City", index: "City", sortable: true, width: 300, search: true, stype: 'text' },
        { name: "Country", index: "Country", sortable: true, width: 300, search: true, stype: 'text' }
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
    pager: "#pager",
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    height: "auto",        
    loadonce: true,       
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "List of Employees",
    ignoreCase: true        
}).jqGrid("filterToolbar", { searchOnEnter: false, stringResult: true, defaultSearch:   "cn" });

 </script>
```

Please look into this code and guide me, where it is getting wrong.

Thanks in advance,
Dipti Sheth

**UPDATED:**

Following is the xml response:

```
      <Rowsets DateCreated="2013-05-02T09:18:07" EndDate="2013-05-02T09:18:07" StartDate="2013-05-02T08:18:07" Version="12.0.6 Build(13)">
<Rowset>
<Columns>
<Column Description="Id" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Id" SQLDataType="12" SourceColumn="Id"/>
<Column Description="ContactName" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="ContactName" SQLDataType="12" SourceColumn="ContactName"/>
<Column Description="City" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="City" SQLDataType="12" SourceColumn="City"/>
<Column Description="Country" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Country" SQLDataType="12" SourceColumn="Country"/>
</Columns>
<Row>
<id>1</id>
<ContactName>Maria Anders</ContactName>
<City>Berlin</City>
<Country>Germany</Country>
</Row>
<Row>
<id>2</id>
<ContactName>Ana Trujillo</ContactName>
<City>México D.F.</City>
<Country>Mexico</Country>
</Row>
<Row>
<id>3</id>
<ContactName>Antonio Moreno</ContactName>
<City>México D.F.</City>
<Country>Mexico</Country>
</Row>
<Row>
<id>4</id>
<ContactName>Thomas Hardy</ContactName>
<City>London</City>
<Country>UK</Country>
</Row>
<Row>
<id>5</id>
<ContactName>Christina Berglund</ContactName>
<City>Luleå</City>
<Country>Sweden</Country>
</Row>
<Row>
<id>6</id>
<ContactName>Hanna Moos</ContactName>
<City>Mannheim</City>
<Country>Germany</Country>
</Row>
</Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

**RESPONSE HEADER:**    in Network tab of debugger of Chrome

```
Cache-Control:private, max-age=0
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:636
Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 09 Jul 2014 12:34:15 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcUHJvamVjdHNcanFHcmlkU2FtcGxlXGpxR3JpZFNhbXBsZVxHZXREYXRhLmFzbXhcTG9hZERhdGE=?=
ConsoleSearchEmulationRendering
```

Thanks,
Dipti Sheth

**EDITED:**
**_Layout.cshtml page:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

   <link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"  media="screen" type="text/css" />
   <link href="~/Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
   <style>
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 75%;            
    }
   </style>
   <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/js/src/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
   $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
   </script>  
   <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  </head> 
  <body> 

   <div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()       
   </div>

   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
   @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
 </body>
 </html>
```

**Index.cshtml page:**

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
  }

  <table id="jqGrid" ></table>
  <div id="pager"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    /*global $ */
    /*jslint browser: true */
   //  $(function () {
   //  "use strict";
      $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
      url: "GetData.asmx/GetData/LoadData",        
      datatype: "xml",     
      xmlReader: {
      repeatitems: false,           
      root: "Rowset",
      row: "Row"
    },
    colNames: ["Id","Contact Name", "City", "Country"],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 40, stype: 'text',sortable:true },
        { name: "ContactName", index: "ContactName", sortable: true, width: 300, search: true, stype: 'text' },
        { name: "City", index: "City", sortable: true, width: 300, search: true, stype: 'text'  },
        { name: "Country", index: "Country", sortable: true, width: 300, search: true, stype: 'text'  }
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 50, 100],
    pager: "#pager",
    gridview: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    height: "auto",        
    loadonce: true,       
    sortorder: "desc",
    caption: "List of Employees",
    ignoreCase: true        
}).jqGrid("filterToolbar", { searchOnEnter: false, stringResult: true, defaultSearch: "cn" });
 // });
  //]]>  
  </script>
```

It shows blank page if  **$(function () {})** is there. If I comment this part, then it shows grid and data on the web-page. But still, toolbar searching does not work.

Please guide me where it's going wrong.

Comment: @DiptiSheth: I couldn't reproduce the error using the data which you posted. Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DiptiSheth.htm).

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks for the demo. It works fine when it works as standalone HTML page, but not with MVC pattern. Tht's strange. Please check my MVC code in EDITED part of the question. THanks

Comment: @DiptiSheth: Sorry, but it should be really no difference between loading XML data from a static file and loading dynamic data. One suspected part which I see in your code is `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` **after** including jQuery and jQuery UI explicitly before. It could overwrite some settings made previously. You can place `$(function () {...});` back and move the Javascript code to the `<head>`. The error number which you posted before is very strange. It shows that the error take place inside of `reloadGrid`. It not exist in the code which you posted.

Comment: @Oleg: Hey...Thanks a lot..it works wonderfully :) . I've commented `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` and placed back `$(function () {...});`. It works perfectly fine irrespective of moving javascript to `<head>`.  Thanks a lot again. You made my day !!

Comment: @DiptiSheth: Is the problem solved after removing the second inclusion of jQuery by `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`? If it's so then I would add the corresponding short answer to help other people who could have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you included jQuery JavaScripts files **twice**. At the first time you include there in `<head>` by

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/js/src/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```

later you placed JavaScripts files of jqGrid and other. The problem is that you use

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

near to the end of `<body>`. The second including of jQuery definitions can overwrite some previously set extensions of jQuery or **reset** / **overwrite** some previously initialized internal structures of jQuery.

The simple rule is: you have to include every JavaScript file **only once** on every HTML page.

Additionally I personally prefer to place JavaScript code inside of `<head>`. In the case you should place the code which creates the grid inside of `$(function () {/*here*/});`