# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rowactions' of undefined in jqGrid for formatter:'action'

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter, free-jqgrid

I am using **jqGrid V 4.6.0.** and trying to implement grid with inline edit/delete functionality.I used formatter:'actions' for acheive this and also getting edit/delete icons in each row.But when i click on those icons i am getting following error in console :**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rowactions' of undefined** and nothing happens in grid.same code and same example i've implemented before with **jqGrid V4.4.4** and it worked well ,but in **V4.6.0** i got this error.Please somebody help me.Thanks in advance :)

**Code for reference:**
  jQuery("#theGrid").jqGrid({

```
    url: '/Student/Grid',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ['Id', 'Firstname', 'Middlename', 'Lastname', 'Birthdate', 'Birthplace', 'State', 'Nationality', 'Religion', 'Ishandicaped ?', 'Actions'],
    colModel: [
        { key: true, name: 'Id', sortable: true, resize: true, align: "center" },
        { key: false, name: 'FirstName', index: 'FirstName', editable: true, align: "center", editrules: { required: true } },
        { key: false, name: 'MiddleName', index: 'MiddleName', editable: true, align: "center", editrules: { required: true } },
        { key: false, name: 'LastName', index: 'LastName', editable: true, align: "center", editrules: { required: true } },
        {
            key: false, name: 'Birthdate', index: 'Birthdate', editable: true, align: "center", editrules: { required: true }, formatter: 'date', editoptions: {
                dataInit: function (el) {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $(el).datepicker({
                            dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                            autoSize: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            changeMonth: true,
                            showButtonPanel: true,
                            showWeek: true
                        });
                    }, 200);
                }
            }
        },
        { key: false, name: 'Birthplace', index: 'Birthplace', editable: true, align: "center", editrules: { required: true } },
        { key: false, name: 'State', index: 'State', editable: true, align: "center", edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "GJ:Gujarat;MH:Maharashtra;DL:Delhi;BNG:Banglore;RJ:Rajasthan" }, editrules: { required: true } },
        { key: false, name: 'Nationality', index: 'Nationality', editable: true, align: "center", editrules: { required: true } },
        { key: false, name: 'Religion', index: 'Religion', editable: true, align: "center", editrules: { required: true } },
        {
            key: false, name: 'IsHandicaped', index: 'IsHandicaped', editable: true, align: "center", edittype: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "True:False" }, formatter: Demo1
        },
        {
            key: false,
            name: 'Actions',
            index: 'tax',
            width: 80,
            align: "center",
            formatter: 'actions',
            formatoptions: {

                delOptions: { url: '/Student/Delete' }
            }
        }
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rownumbers: true,
    autowidth: true,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
    pager: '#gridPager',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    reloadAfterSubmit: true,
    altclass: 'table table-bordered table-striped',
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false
    },
    caption:'Studentdata JqGrid V4.4.4',
    editurl: '/Student/Edit',
    mtype: "post",
    height: '100%',
    hiddengrid: false,

    serializeRowData: function (postData) {
        debugger;
        // new row id is "new_row"
        postData.Id == "jqg1" ? postData.oper = "add" : postData.oper = "add";
           return postData;
    },
        afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
            if (response.responseText == "") {
                $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam',
                { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid'); //Reloads the grid after Add
                return [true, ''];
            } else {
                $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam',
                { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid'); //Reloads the grid after Add
                return [false, response.responseText];
            }
        }
    }




});
```

Comment: Could you provide the demo which demonstrates the problem. The code which you post contains many suspected or unneeded option and properties. Some properties are undefined (like `formatter: Demo1`). You included `free-jqGrid`, but you write that you use version 4.6.0. [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) is fork of 4.7. It's first version was 4.8 and the current is 4.9.2 (or 4.9.3-pre). Which version you use really?

Comment: /**
 * @license jqGrid  4.6.0 - jQuery Grid
 * Copyright (c) 2008, Tony Tomov, tony@trirand.com
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Date: 2014-02-20
 */
I am really using 4.6.0 version.

Comment: And about formatter Demo1 its just a customer formatter i've made to show text color of coloumn based on some condition like this:
function Demo1(cellvalue, options, student) {
        if (cellvalue == true) {
            return '<p style="color:#68B167">' + cellvalue + '</p>';
        }
        else {
            return '<p style="color:#c42a27">' + cellvalue + '</p>';
        }
    }

Comment: The problem is very easy. If you use jqGrid 4.6.0 then you should remove  [free-jqgrid](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/free-jqgrid/info) tag from your question. Formatter `formatter: 'actions'` works in 4.6.0, but if you get the error "Cannot read property 'rowactions' of undefined" then you have probably *some error in your code*. For example you included .js files in wrong way. So **you should provide the demo which reproduce the error**. One will see which js files you include and how you use exactly jqGrid. You can use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for example.

Comment: I included files as follows:
@Scripts.Render("/bundles/jquery")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>

Comment: I wrote you that you should **provide the demo** which can be debugged. What you posted in the last comment could be the same problem like in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24676045/315935) where one included *the second* `@Scripts.Render("/bundles/jquery")` at the wrong place. You should examine exactly **how you defined the bundles**. I suggest you to use no bundles at the beginning and to use `jquery.jqGrid.scr.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. The `grid.locale-en.js` should be included before `jquery.jqGrid.scr.js`. Just open source of resulting HTML and examine it exactly.